# Import a specific version of Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I have a face detection script running in Flask app on Apache2 server in Raspebrry pi # model B+. Whenever I'm tying to access the app script is looking for Opencv 3.3 version which I already uninstalled and Installed version 4.1.1.

**Installed version Opencv:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.1.1'
>>>
```

How to force the script to import Opencv 4.1.1?

**myscript.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, Response
videoStreamBp = Blueprint('videoStream', __name__)

import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

here I'm getting an error:

> import cv2
>
> [Tue Mar 03 17:32:20.727754 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 11745:tid 1964926000] [remote 192.168.225.53:62910]
>
> ImportError: libopencv_reg.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid conflicts between different versions of project dependencies you should use virtual environments.
virtual environments are created mainly for this purpose.

> the main purpose of Python virtual environments is to create an isolated environment for Python projects. This means that each project can have its own dependencies, regardless of what dependencies every other project has.

the above quote is taken from this [site](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) and I think you should check it out if you need some pointers on how to create and use virtual environments.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that but still is there anyway to explicitly specify the cv2 version?